# how can i pass registered vue component as prop to a component

Tags: vue.js

Need to pass component to child component, using props or you have better way to solve this problem

I registered component needed to pass globally or just registered this component locally. But these solutions can't solve my problem.

Here is my code to register component needed to pass locally:
**a.vue html**

```
<dropdown :icon="UserIcon"></dropdown>
```

**a.vue js**

```
components: {'dropdown', Dropdown, 'icon-user': UserIcon}
```

**dropdown.vue html**

```
<div class="dropdown"><icon></icon></div>
```

**dropdown.vue js**

```
props: ['icon']
```

**UserIcon.vue**

```
<i class="user-icon"></i>
```

the browser reminds me that icon is unknown custom element. It seems like vue does not support this way to use component, doesn't it?

Comment: So you want the `UserIcon` component to nest inside the `dropdown`? Why not just put it inside the default `<slot>`?

Comment: you are right, and i did it right now. It works~and could I ask another question that how to pass more component in dropdown component?

Comment: Could you spend time to read my answer of this question? I show my lastest code there.

Answer (score 2):

I solve this problem using slot.

and there is another question comes...

a.vue

```
<dropdown><template v-slot:icon><icon-user></icon-user></template></dropdown>
```

dropdown.vue

```
<div class="dropdown"><slot name="icon"></slot></div>
```

But icon-user component didn't show...

***and I did this work, cuz I remove the name attribute of slot.***
a.vue

```
<dropdown><template><icon-user></icon-user></template></dropdown>
```

dropdown.vue

```
<div class="dropdown"><slot></slot></div>
```

Comment: Ok....I solved this one. `v-slot="icon"` which is from official [link](website:https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html), doesn't work. However you can write `slot="icon"`, it work!!